# How to sort $ n $ objects of $ k $ categories into queue.

Tags: combinatorics

How can $18$ animals be queued, if $5$ of them are lions, $6$ of them are monkeys, $7$ of them are dogs and no two monkeys can be beside each other. I know that it is a basic problem of combinatorics, but I am not able to deal with it, sorry.

Any help will be appreciated. (I am supposed that how the lions (monkeys, dogs) are queued is doesn't matter).

So I have tried to compute all possible queues in this form $$\frac{18!}{5!6!7!}$$ and then I have tried to subtract the number of possibilities when they are beside each other (and with this part I have troubles). Or is there some easier way how to compute this?

Comment: Ignore the monkeys for now.  Arrange the lions and dogs first.  Now... leave a bit of open space to the side of each lion/dog and insert at most one monkey into each available space.  This guarantees us that no two monkeys are adjacent.

Comment: Alternatively, first arrange the monkeys so that no two are next to one another, then fill the remaining spots with dogs and lions.  There are $5$ spaces between the monkeys, so we have $7$ spaces left, and $7$ places to put them.  Stars and bars.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have tried this in this form, suppose that I have no monkeys, so I have $11$ animals I can put them into the queue $\frac{11!}{5!6!}$ and then there are $12$ gaps where I can put monkeys, so I have $ {12}\choose{7}$. So the number of possibilities how to queued them is  $\frac{11!}{5!6!}\cdot$  ${12}\choose{7}$. Am I correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes (*after the edit*), once you take care of one more typo being the number of animals which are not monkeys is actually $5+7=12$ that appears correct., again, assuming that each lion is considered identical, each monkey is considered identical, etc...  You might for practice also look at the problem where each animal is considered distinct.

Comment: @Waney  You seem to be confusing the numbers of monkeys and dogs.  There are five lions and seven dogs, which can be arranged in $\binom{12}{7}$ ways.  That creates $13$ gaps in which to place the six monkeys.

Comment: Yes I have made mistake. So now I believe that correctly it is $\frac{12!}{5!7!}\cdot$ ${13}\choose{6}$. When we suppose that all animal are distinct, then we have $12!\cdot$ ${13}\choose{6}$$6!$. It is ok now, thanks for all help.